# How to Checkout Tags Using C# and Git?

Tags: c#, git

I have a console application that uses content from a certain git repository. It does the following:

- Pulls the content from the Git repo
- Organizes it in a certain way
- Moves the organized content to a different location

The problem is the second item. The content should be organized and processed based on a given Git tag. Currently, the C# console app can clone the repo, but now I need it to checkout all of the tags in the repo, one-by-one. After checking each tag out, the console application should process the files, and then move on to the next tag.

How can my C# console app check out the tags? I would want to just use the native Git commands like `git checkout tags/<tagname>`

Comment: I would have found it quite easier to use Libgit2sharp: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this was actually fairly simple. I created a generic Git command method like so, using a new process and then reading from the StandardOutput. I then returned all of the StandardOutput as one comma-delimited string that could be iterated over later.

```
public string RunGitCommand(string command, string args, string workingDirectory)
{
    string git = "git";
    var results = "";
    var proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = git,
            Arguments = $"{command} {args}",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
        }
    };
        proc.Start();
        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            results += $"{proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()},";
        }
        proc.WaitForExit();
        return results;    
 }
```

This allowed me to then call for the tags like so

```
var tags = RunGitCommand("tag", "", $"{location}"); // get all tags
```

Finally, I could then iterate over all of the tags and check them out with the `RunGitCommand` method I wrote above. For each iterated tag, I could do something like, where `tag` is the individual element in my list of tags.

```
git.RunGitCommand("checkout", $"tags/{tag}", $"{location}");
```